# Google Sheet copying and paste values and formatting between different sheets

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste

I have been trying to make a script to work for copying and pasting data between two different sheets and I have read all the posts at this forum. Many solutions are too old and don't work anymore and other simply go to different kind of error. I have read Google documentation and tried some stuff, but I could not make it works. I will post here one script I have found and modified that comes closer to what I need, but it fails in some aspects. I need only values (and if possible, formatting too), I don't want to past any of the formulas from the source sheet.

```
function copiarValores2(){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1hWTdUNhTEohOqg-UGNGV4XwY7nDOX5Ys9piz256QeIc');
  var sourceS = source.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sourceS.getRange('A1:S230');
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15zvklK7NAEBKQcusTwYPEmlH3BNw0t-6MlgQ1fqBuPs');
  var destSheet = destination.getSheets()[0];
  range.copyValuesToRange(destSheet,1,20,1,230)
}
```

Running this script I have the following error:

```
Exception: Target sheet and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.
```

I don't know how to fix this.
Thanks for attention and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not possible to copy a range to a different spreadsheet directly, You can use this workaround:

### Sample Code:

```
function copiarValores2() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1PTRabYcpVY6hLNvUByj9ZJAouogc-uMCMhiexxxxx');
  var sourceS = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1RPQ7WOTOZZSirf60kP6nULhViCdsuGHcOxxxxxx');
  var destSheet = destination.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //Copy source sheet to destination spreadsheet
  newSource = sourceS.copyTo(destination);
  //Get the range from the newly copied sheet
  var range = newSource.getRange('A1:S230');

  //Copy to the destination sheet, starting from cell A1
  range.copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A1"));

  //Delete copied source sheet
  destination.deleteSheet(newSource);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Open a source spreadsheet and select a sheet to be copied using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
2. Open a destination spreadsheet and select a sheet where the values will be pasted using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
3. Copy your source sheet to your destination spreadsheet using [Sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet). This copied sheet will be your new source sheet which is located in your destination spreadsheet.

> The copied sheet is named "Copy of [original name]" in your destination spreadsheet

4. Select the range you want to copy from your new source sheet then copy the range to your destination sheet using [Range.copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

> I used this method since you mentioned in your post that you also want to copy the formatting. You can use other copy methods available in [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) based on your preference

5. Lastly, delete your new source sheet in your destination spreadsheet using [Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)

---

### OUTPUT:

**Source Sheet:**

[image]

**Destination Sheet:**

[image]

Comment: Ron M, first, thank you very much for both code and explanation, that's make all the difference for me. But there is an issue here. When the new sheet is created, all the formulas come together and many values come from IMPORTRANGE function. I need a copy only with the values, because these data come from Forms and the source sheet will be erased every moth, so I need a copy every month with the last data before erease it. If it comes with IMPORTRANGE, these data will change.

Comment: Oh, this might be tricky, can you try using this code first `Utilities.sleep(30000); range.copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A1"),{contentsOnly:true});` When i tried this, this will  give time for the importrange formula to load before copying its value. But then again I manually gave access to it for the first time for it to work. Let me know if you encountered similar issue.

Comment: You might also want to consider modifying the steps. example copy your source sheet to a dummy destination sheet in your source spreadsheet (paste as values) then copy that sheet to your destination spreadsheet. Let me know if you need support on implementing this as well

Comment: Perfect, "{contentsOnly:true}); " worked perfect. I even didn't tried sleep(30000) and the new sheet loaded immediately with all the data that was present at source sheet. Thank you again, helped me to solve this issue and enabled me to learn more.